# finding a combination sum to match a particular sum

Tags: c#, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, tensor

Given an array containing 2 - 3 values in each of the up to 100+ elements find the combination that adds to a particular total. The problem with this is that trying each combination will take 3^100+ operations which is obviously not realistic. the one thing that helps is that the first of the 3 elements is the most likely to be correct. I have a new Nvidia RTX 2080ti that contains thousands of cuda & tensor cores and I would like to put those to work.

I have tried iterating through all the possible combinations however this is not realistic. I am also looking into path finder algorithms which should reduce the workload however i think my best bet would be putting my GPU to work on this problem.

Comment: I only meant to vote for the duplicate, forgot I had this uber power. Please let me know if the dupe isn't correct.

Comment: Not a dupe; please reopen.

Comment: What do you mean by "an array containing 2 - 3 values in each of the up to 100+ elements"? What do you mean by a "combination"?

Comment: What i mean by 2-3 values in an element is basically a multidimensional array:
a b c
a2 b2 c2
...
i need to add combinations like a + a2, a +b2 ... to equal a known sum of the elements to find which combinations equal the known sum